# Angular 5 form data post issue

Tags: angular5, angular4-forms, angular-httpclient

When i am trying to submit angular form i am getting cannot read property value error
console screen error:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
html

```
 <div class="panel-body">
          <form [formGroup]="angForm" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4">Coin Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name" #name />
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['name'].invalid && (angForm.controls['name'].dirty || angForm.controls['name'].touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
              <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['name'].errors.required">
                Name is required.
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4">Coin Price</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="language" #price/>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['language'].invalid && (angForm.controls['language'].dirty || angForm.controls['language'].touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
              <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['language'].errors.required">
                Price is required.
              </div>
            </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <button (click)="addBooks(name.value, language.value)" [disabled]="angForm.pristine || angForm.invalid" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
              </div>
          </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: I think you have to add name attribute for input controls

Comment: Are you using reactive form approach?
just remove #name and try

Comment: Yes I am using reactformmodule @AnoopBabuam

Comment: Thanks It worked. @AnoopBabu.